# How to extract names with initials from a paragraph using Python and its libraries?

Tags: python, regex

I am currently working on a project where I have to give a label to each paragraph according to the topics that it contains.

In order to do this, I am extracting each paragraph from many **word documents(.docx)**. After this I am passing it through Universal Sentence Encoder to get an embedding and then running a Kmeans clustering on them.

This is giving me a pretty accurate set of paragraphs for each label.
But I want to further extract only the names present in the document.

Here are a variety of sample paragraphs that I am working on:

> Sri. SHASHANK KUMAR, S/o.Sri.Rajat Kumar, aged about 45 years,
> residing at ADDRESS Hereinafter called as the VENDOR.
>
> Sri. M. S. ANANTHKRISHNA ,aged about 46 years, S/o. Sri. M.Neelakant
> residing at ADDRESSS. Hereinafter called the SECOND PARTY (PURCHASER).
>
> Smt. GANGA A.K, D/o. Sri. Mukesh, aged about 31 years, residing at
> ADDRESS Hereinafter called the PURCHASER.
>
> SRI.SANTHOSH BHAT.N.C S/o.Sri. Chikkabasappa, aged about 29 years,
> residing at ADDRESS Hereinafter called the PURCHASER.

Not only that there are multiple paragraphs where there are spaces SRI. and no spaces between Sri. and name. There are also instaces where they have used D/o, W/o and even C/o. The start of the sentence only contains Sri, Smt, SRI or SMT.

I tried using regex with the `re.findall()` method.
Pattern for matching:

`Sri. [A-Z\s]*|SRI.[A-Z\s]*|Smt. [A-z\s]*|SMT.[A-Z\s]*|SRI. [A-z\s]*|SMT. [A-Z\s]*`

I also tried using nltk to split it into sentences and then tagging the words based on the stanford NERTagger but this also did not work. I even tried using spacy to assing PROPN tag to the names but this also is not considering the intials in the name.

Here is how I have written the functions:

```
def get_vendor_purchaser_details(df_hierchical_clustered_output):
    df_vendor_purchaser_details = df_hierchical_clustered_output[df_hierchical_clustered_output['k_means_labels_primary'] == 4][["id", "filename", "para_text"]]

    vendor_detail_list = []
    for index, row in df_vendor_purchaser_details.iterrows():
        vendor_detail = {}
        vendor_detail["id"] = row["id"]
        vendor_detail["para_text"] = row["para_text"]
        vendor_detail["name"] = get_vendor_name(row)

        vendor_detail_list.append(vendor_detail)
        print(vendor_detail["name"])
```

```
def get_vendor_name(entry):
    para_text = entry["para_text"]
    # name_pattern = r'Sri. [A-Z\s]*|SRI.[A-Z\s]*|Smt. [A-z\s]*|SMT.[A-Z\s]*|SRI. [A-z\s]*|SMT. [A-Z\s]*'
    # vendor_name = re.findall(name_pattern,para_text)
----------------------------------------------------
    # if "S/o" in para_text:
    #     vendor_name = para_text.split("S/o")[0]
    # elif "D/o" in para_text:
    #     vendor_name = para_text.split("D/o")[0]
    # elif "C/o" in para_text:
    #     vendor_name = para_text.split("C/o")[0]
    # elif "W/o" in para_text:
    #     vendor_name = para_text.split("W/o")[0]
    # else:
    #     vendor_name = ""

    # return vendor_name
```

The above paragraph includes the regex attempt and also an attempt where I split the string to access the names.

Please let me know how I can extract the whole name with the initials.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's clearly not so easy to get these persons out of your text by handling all cases. I've tried [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/dZD9ZY/1) and it might help you.

Comment: Can you grab from the beginning until the first comma (`,`)?

Comment: How would you be able to tell that `residing` is not part of the name in `S/o. Sri. M.Neelakant residing` ? Is that a given?